# Same code showing different behaviour in XCode

Tags: ios, nsurl, nsurlrequest

```
-(IBAction)onButtonClick:(id)sender
{
    DowloadFilesManager* downManager1=[[DowloadFilesManager alloc] init];
    DowloadFilesManager* downManager2=[[DowloadFilesManager alloc] init];
    DowloadFilesManager* downManager3=[[DowloadFilesManager alloc] init];
    [downManager1 downloadURL:@"http://localhost/banners/banner1.jpg" destPath:@"/Users/varunisac/Desktop/samples/godisgreat.jpg"];
    [downManager2 downloadURL:@"http://localhost/banners/banner1.jpg" destPath:@"/Users/varunisac/Desktop/samples/godisgreat1.jpg"];
    [downManager3 downloadURL:@"http://localhost/banners/banner1.jpg" destPath:@"/Users/varunisac/Desktop/samples/godisgreat2.jpg"];
    NSLog(@"Finished Succesfully");
}
```

1)The Above code works Perfect
2) It  downloads  the jpgs after firing  the   following event function.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);
    [receivedData writeToFile:toFile  atomically:YES];
    theConnection = nil;
    receivedData = nil;    
}
```

But It DOES NOT fires any event methods while  i tried on another programme after importing the "DowloadFilesManager.h" and  "DowloadFilesManager.m" which runs on the same XCode on the same Mac machine with the server URLs reachable.Can anyone suggest a solution ? Am i missing anything? I tried Clean etc...but doesnt work. Following is the DowloadFilesManager class which i used:

```
#import "DowloadFilesManager.h"
@implementation DowloadFilesManager
@synthesize toFile;
@synthesize toURL;
@synthesize  theConnection;
-(void) downloadURL:(NSString *) urlStr destPath:(NSString *) destPath
{
    toURL=urlStr;
    toFile=destPath;
    // Create the request.
    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:toURL]
    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
    timeoutInterval:60.0];
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    // [receivedData dataWithCapacity: 0];
    // create the connection with the request
    // and start loading the data
    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if (!theConnection) {
    // Release the receivedData object.
    receivedData = nil;
     // Inform the user that the connection failed.
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Append the new data to receivedData.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    [receivedData appendData:data];  
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
    theConnection = nil;
    receivedData = nil;
    // inform the user
    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
    [error localizedDescription],
    [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);

}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);
    [receivedData writeToFile:toFile  atomically:YES];
    theConnection = nil;
    receivedData = nil;   
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Within `- (void)downloadURL:destPath:`, you have created a local variable called `theConnection`:

```
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [...];
```

and when the method ends, this will go out of scope and be destroyed.

What you want is the following, to use your property to persist the connection object:

```
self.theConnection = [...];
```

Also, a better approach to signal failure would be to make that method return `BOOL` and use this statement:

```
return self.theConnection != nil;
```